# NATing with windows server 2012

Tags: windows, nat

Greetings and thank you in advance for your help,

My setup is just like this:

**computer 1**

Windows 8.1 with one interface configured like the following

```
ipv4       : 172.19.209.130
mask       : 255.255.255.252
default GW : 172.19.209.129
```

connection has no Internet available .

**computer 2**

Windows server 2012 R2 with two interfaces

interface 1 configured as following

```
ipv4       : 172.19.209.129
mask       : 255.255.255.252
default GW : 172.19.209.130
```

connection has no Internet available .

interface 2 configured as following

```
ipv4       : 192.168.7.66
mask       : 255.255.254.0
default GW : 192.168.7.1
```

connection has Internet available .

I have been struggling to give computer 1 Internet through NATing computer 2 connections with no success ..

So, what I am looking for is to have Internet on computer 1 through it's connection with computer's 2 first connection which is somehow NATed to the Internet capable interface ..

I added routing and remote access role, configured it as shown on many websites on the Internet (easy using the provided wizard) but still no Internet on the client, any configurations to take place on the client side ??

Comment: [Set up Network Bridge](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783728(v=ws.10).aspx)?

Comment: What kind of tests have you done? How is DNS configured? Can you traceroute to a public address, such as Google's DNS (8.8.8.8)?